# Extract a string in C++

Tags: c++, c++11

I know such question are asked many times but I have a real hard time to extract a string from a large string.
I have a string that looks like this:

```
GET /analysis HTTP/1.1

Host: localhost:4433

User-Agent: curl/7.47.0

Accept: */*

Authorization: Basic MTIzYWxpY2U6bWVyY3VyeQ==

Content-Length: 40

Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded



{"u_id": 62, "g_id": 14, "a_type": "LR"}
```

I wanted to extract `MTIzYWxpY2U6bWVyY3VyeQ==` but `MTIzYWxpY2U6bWVyY3VyeQ==` could be anything but `Authorization: Basic`  would be definitely there I do not have boost library. I also do not want any whitespace character around the extracted string.

Comment: If you are interested in regular expressions, the standard library has a [regular expressions library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex)

Comment: I recommend `std::istringstream`.  The `':'` character appears to be a field separator.  See `std::getline` where you can set the delimiter to `':'`.

Comment: I believe with find and substr I could do that but still not able to. Do not want to use regex header for just this string extraction.

Comment: Is using an actual HTTP parser out of the question?

Comment: I just needed to get Authorization header value. Jack Of Blades answer resolved my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fortunately, string contains member functions to achieve this, albeit somebody may come up with a "cooler" solution, this works(and is intended to do just that either way) :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

int main(){
    std::ostringstream oss;
    oss << "GET /analysis HTTP/1.1\n\n"
        << "Host: localhost:4433\n\n"
        << "User-Agent: curl/7.47.0\n\n"
        << "Accept: */*\n\n"
        << "Authorization: Basic MTIzYWxpY2U6bWVyY3VyeQ==\n\n"
        << "Content-Length: 40\n\n"
        << "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\n\n"
        << "{\"u_id\": 62, \"g_id\": 14, \"a_type\": \"LR\"}";

    std::string content = oss.str();

    std::string delimiterStart = "Basic ";
    std::string delimiterEnd = " ";

    int start = content.find(delimiterStart) + delimiterStart.length();
    std::string partial = content.substr(start, content.length());
    partial = partial.substr(0, partial.find(delimiterEnd));

    std::cout<<"STR: "<< partial;
    return 0;
}
```

This is presuming that you know two delimiters, which you will need whatever the case is, otherwise how would you extract anything if you don't know from where to where to "grab" anything?

Comment: The lines almost certainly end `\r\n`, not `\n\n`, and you'll need an extra `\r\n` pair after the `Content-Type` line. Basic HTTP :)

Answer (score 0):

I know regular expressions are terribly overused but just for posterity's sake here's a solution using regular expressions.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>
using namespace std;

std::string source = R"(GET /analysis HTTP/1.1

Host: localhost:4433

User-Agent: curl/7.47.0

Accept: */*

Authorization: Basic MTIzYWxpY2U6bWVyY3VyeQ==

Content-Length: 40

Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded



{"u_id": 62, "g_id": 14, "a_type": "LR"})";

int main() {
    std::smatch match;
    std::regex reg(R"(Authorization:[\s]*Basic[\s]*([^\s]+))");

    std::regex_search(source,match,reg);

    if(match.size() >=2) {
        std::cout << match[1] << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```